# Trying to solve the equation involving floor function

Tags: functional-equations

I am trying to solve the following equation:

Floor[logx+1]+x=11

Where Floor function returns the greatest integer smaller than the value in bracket.
e.g. Floor[3.3] = 3

And the logarithm is to the base 10

I tried using WolframAlpha, but it's timing out.

EDIT:  I gather from the responses that a solution does not have a method.
-----  If I change the equation to the following:

```
log(x) + x = 11
```

Here logarithm is to the base 10.
Is it solvable now?  I am more interested in method.

Thanks,
Siddharth

Comment: There's no solution.

Comment: On the other hand if you mean $\lfloor\log(x+1)\rfloor+x=11$, the answer is $10$.

Comment: [Maple output](http://i.imgur.com/7Ojrm.jpg)

Comment: @Raskolnikov There is a solution and it's 10, as mentioned by Andre Nicolas.  I am interested in the methodology.

Comment: @SidCool: André changed the function.

Comment: solution is given by $$ x=\frac{W(10^{11}\ln(10))}{\ln(10)}$$ , where W is [Lambert W function](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

Comment: @SidCool: The original question was not typeset in LaTeX, and there was in my mind some ambiguity about what was intended. The two plausible guesses are $\lfloor \log(x)+1\rfloor +x=11$ and $\lfloor \log(x+1)\rfloor +x=11$. Which one was intended?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's clear that the expression on the left hand side of the equation is defined for $x>0$ and in this domain it's monotonically increasing. It's also clear that for very small $x$ it will be negative, and for $x=10$ it's already larger than $11$. So if a solution exists it will be in $(0,10)$.

You can split this domain into the integer values that $[\log x + 1]$ gets:
on $[10^{n-1},10^n)$ it takes value $n$. So immediately we can rule out $[1,10)$ to contain a solution, since it takes value $1$, requiring $1 + x = 11$ which leaves only $x=10$ which is not a solution.

Similarly for all whole $n<1$ a solution has to satisfy that $x \in [10^{n-1},10^n) \implies n + x = 11 \implies x = 11-n \implies x>10$ which is obviously a contradiction.

Therefore there are no solutions.

Comment: Thanks for the response, @davin. If we remove the floor function and just have it


logx + x = 11

Is there a solution?

Comment: @SidCool, absolutely, and that is easily proved with IVP: $\log x + x$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$ with negative values for small $x$ and positive values for $x \geq 1$ so there must be a solution on $(0,1)$. It's also monotonic, so that will be the only solution.

Comment: Thanks @Davin.  Is there a standard method for solving such equations?

Comment: @SidCool, I'm not aware of any standard method. Everything I wrote is standard material in a real analysis course, but I'm not sure of anything more specific.

Answer (score 2):

Left side is an increasing function (as sum of a nondecreasing and increasing), so there is at most one solution. Also you can get rid of "+1" from floor:

$\lfloor \log x\rfloor + 1 + x = 11$

$\lfloor \log x\rfloor + x = 10$

If $x<10$ then $\log x<1$ so $\lfloor \log x \rfloor \leq 0$ so $\lfloor \log x \rfloor + x < 10$

If $x\geq 10$ then $\log x \geq 1$ so $\lfloor \log x \rfloor \geq 1$ so $\lfloor \log x \rfloor + x > 10$.